# Three.js detect click on none transparent pixel of object texture

Tags: three.js

I have couple of THREE.PlaneGeometry with a texture of human faces that are png with transparent pixels around the face.

I am using THREE.Raycaster to detect objects under mouse pointer, when I get the list of intersects - I need to know if the click was on transparent pixel, and if this is the case - move to the next intersect object.

Something like this:

```
var onStageMouseDown = function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // stageEl - is the element that contain the renderer
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 
        ( event.offsetX / stageEl.offsetWidth ) * 2 - 1, 
        - ( event.offsetY / stageEl.offsetHeight ) * 2 + 1, 
        0.5 );

    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    // objects - is list of meshes
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );    

    for(var i=0; i<intersects.length; i++) {

        // this is what I don't know how to calculate....
        var PointIsTransparentPixelOnMeshTexture = ?;

        if ( PointIsTransparentPixelOnMeshTexture ) continue;

        alert( "You clicked on "+intersects[i].object.name );
        return;

        }


    alert( "You clicked no one " );

    }
```

any Ideas?

thanks.

Comment: what kind of mesh you working on? THREE.Mesh, THREE.PointCloud

Comment: THREE.Mesh ( Plane + Image texture )

Comment: I want to detect click on non-transparent part of the png texture as well. Any ideas?